# Find the general form of $n$th derivative $f(x) = \ln(1+x)$

Tags: derivatives

I think I am doing it the correct way but I am not sure.

Is it $$(-1)^{n+1}n!(1+x)^{-n} ?$$

Thank you guys.

Comment: It should be $ (-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!(1+x)^{-n}\, \forall n\geq 1 $.

Comment: may be, you should show us how you found that so we can help you. When the derivative of your expression for n it doesn't gives the expression for n+1. So it must be wrong ...

Comment: problem solved . thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I would do it

$$f(x) = \ln(1+x)$$
$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{x+1}$$
$$f''(x) = -\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$$
$$f'''(x) = (-1)(-2)\frac{1}{(x+1)^3}$$
$$f'^v(x) = (-1)(-2)(-3)\frac{1}{(x+1)^4}$$
$$f'^v(x) = (-1)^3\cdot \frac{3!}{(x+1)^4}$$
$$.....................$$
$$f'^n(x) = (-1)^{n-1}\cdot \frac{(n-1)!}{(x+1)^{n}}\forall n\ge 1$$