# Find the general form of the $n$th derivative of $\ln^2(x+1)$

Tags: calculus, analysis

$f(x)=\ln^2(x+1)$.

I tried to write $f(x)=\ln (x+1)\cdot\ln (x+1)$ and then apply Leibniz but i think maybe i did something wrong.

Could you explain me the right method?

Comment: Then please write out the expansion for $f^{(n)}$ to show your effort.

Comment: Hint to begin with: $[f(g(x))]' = g'(x) \times f'(g)$

Comment: @Saeed You basically wrote the chain rule.

Comment: @Forester Yes, as the starting point!

Comment: I proved that$(\ln (x+1))^{(k)} = (-1)^{k-1}(k-1)!(x+1)^{-k} $

and\\

$(\ln (x+1))^{(n-k)} = (-1)^{(n-k-1)}(n-k-1)!(x+1)^{-n+k} $ 

And  then i tried the Leibniz formula expresses the derivative on nth order of the product of two functions.

Comment: Is it good what I've done so far?

Comment: Hint: Patterns don't always start from the beginning, sometimes they start later. In this case which derivative would a pattern start?

Comment: Well i think $x^2$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the general form of $n$th derivative $f(x) = \ln(1+x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333820/find-the-general-form-of-nth-derivative-fx-ln1x)

Answer (score 3):

Ok we talked a bit about it in the comments: we can start with the chain rule to find $f'$. Then we calculate a few more derivatives, and eventually we find a nice form that looks like a good guess. That guess can be proven by induction. I will leave the guessing and the proof by induction for you to do. Alright, here we go:
$$f(x) = \ln^2(x+1) $$
$$f'(x) = 2 \times\frac{\ln(x+1)}{x+1} $$
Now we can use $(\frac{u}{v})'=\frac{u'v-v'u}{v^2}$ and the fact that $(\ln(x+1))'=(x+1)^{-1}$ :
$$f''(x) = 2 \times \frac{(x+1)^{-1+1}-\ln(x+1)}{(x+1)^2}=2 \times \frac{1-\ln(x+1)}{(x+1)^2}$$
$$f'''(x) = 2 \times \frac{-(x+1)^{-1+2}-2(x+1)(1-\ln(x+1))}{(x+1)^4}=2 \times \frac{-1-2+2\ln(x+1)}{(x+1)^3}$$
$$f^{(4)}(x)=2\times\frac{2(x+1)^{-1+3}-3(x+1)^2(-1-2+2\ln(x+1))}{(x+1)^6}$$
$$ = 2 \times \frac{2+3\times1+3\times2-3\times2\ln(x+1)}{(x+1)^4}$$
Almost feeling like there's a pattern, right? Let's keep going:
$$f^{(5)}(x) = 2 \times \frac{-3\times2(x+1)^{-1+4}-4(x+1)^3(2+3\times1+3\times2-3\times2\ln(x+1))}{(x+1)^8} $$
$$= 2 \times \frac{-3\times2-4\times2-4\times3\times1-4 \times 3 \times 2 + 4\times3\times2 \ln(x+1)}{(x+1)^5} $$
Curious...let's organize:
$$f^{(5)}(x) = 2 \times \frac{-(4\times3\times2 + 4\times3\times1 + 4\times2\times1+3\times2\times1)+4\times3\times2\times1\times\ln(x+1)}{(x+1)^5} $$
$$= 2 \times \frac{-4!(\frac11+\frac12+\frac13+\frac14)+4!\times\ln(x+1)}{(x+1)^5} $$
Now the general form is evident. I still recommend that you do $f^{(6)}(x)$ yourself before moving on to writing the general form and proving by induction. If you find difficulties with induction, let us know and we will help you. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort!

Comment: You are very welcome.